# command line mount helper for Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, mount

Under Ubuntu there are several mount helpers to support easy mounting of encrypted (cryptsetup/luks) removable media such as USB drives. Under Gnome/Unity/XFCE a requester is opened, just enter the password, and everything is going well.

Is there something like that under Ubuntu Server when logged in on the command line?

`pmount` would be exactly what I am looking for, but does not support `btrfs`, and the maintainer has given up maintaining years ago.

`udisks` does not support encrypted and gets confused by `device-mapper` paths.

Any method to mount it in a single step? Or the manual way with `cryptsetup` an mount?

How exactly does it work under Gnome/Unity/XFCE? Where exactly, in which program would I have to look for the source files?